# $f(n) = k\times 124^n +1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f(n) = 1 + k \times124^n$ where $k$ is a positive integer. Assume there exists distinct integers $m,n \ge 2$ such that either $m,n \mid f(i)$ for all $i$. Prove there exists integer $x \ge 2$ such that $x \mid f(n)$ for all $n$.

---

I tried some small cases like $k=1$, but I didn't see any patterns. For $k=1$, I noticed that $f(1) = 125 = 5^3$ and that $f(2)$ was prime. Could that mean that one of the numbers must be $f(2)?$ and what could $r$ be. I also noticed that $f(1) \mid f(3)$ if $k=1$. However, I couldn't see this in the $k=2$ case, at least for the terms I could compute. However, for $k=2$ I noticed divisibility by $3$. I tried finding a contriadiction and find possible $x$, but I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Didn't you post this earlier today?

Comment: Yes, but I was told that it was not meeting guidelines so I added more Information and reposted after deleting the old one. Sorry if that is not what to do, I am new to this site I got recommended by my middle school just a few months ago.

Comment: +1 : nice work shown.

Comment: @WWesEEE  In the future, you should know it is never okay to repost a question that wans't received well, or was closed.  If a question of yours is closed, what you need to do is *edit the closed question" for it to be reviewed for reopening.  You broke the rules of this site by posting this question, after it was closed.  Please know that the closure of the post, and your deletion of it, and the downvotes on it, will count in in the tally that may determine whether you are restricted from asking questions on this site.

Comment: I'm so,so sorry. I will be sure to keep that in mind.

Comment: @WWesEEE  I'm not trying to scold you or scare you, but I don't want you to become another asker that gets banned from asking questions, so I wanted' to provide you with more information.

Comment: Well I'm glad you improved the post; try to include context like you did here, whenever you ask, and you'll not have to worry about closed post!  Best of luck :-)

Comment: For your intuition, assuming that $k=1$: [1] I confirmed that $f(2) = 15377$ is indeed a prime number [2] $f(1) = 5^3$ [3] $f(4)$ is not divisible by either $f(2)$ or by $5$.  Therefore, by the premise of the problem, you may **discount** the value $k=1$, as an **unacceptable** value for $(k)$, since the value of $(k=1)$ **violates the premises**.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?  In my opinion, this problem is too advanced for any pre-college math class, despite the fact that an elegant basic-math-algebra-only demonstration may be possible.

Comment: I am actually a middle schooler preparing for math Olympiad contests, this is not standard school math.

Comment: @user2661923 Perhaps you are not familiar with the math Olympiad world, but this is actually a fair problem for middle school students.

Comment: @WhatsUp math Olympiad problems are way too advanced for me, as I suspect they are for 98% of high school math students.  Further, the OP has yet to indicate the source of the problem.

Comment: I will try to find the source, it was in a problem set which did not include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $m, n$ are prime numbers, which are both prime to $k$ and $124$.

Now consider $f(1)$, $f(2)$ and $f(3)$. We may assume that two of them are divisible by $m$, say $f(a), f(b)$ with $1 \leq a < b \leq 3$.

We have then $m \mid f(b) - f(a) = k(124^b - 124^a)$.

If $b - a = 1$, then we have $m \mid 123$. It follows that for any integer $c$, we have $f(c) \equiv 1 + k \cdot 124^c \equiv 1 + k\mod m$. Therefore $f(c) \equiv f(a) \equiv 0\mod m$ for any $c$.

If $b - a = 2$, then $a, b = 1, 3$ and we have $m \mid 124^2 - 1 = 123 \times 125$. The case $m \mid 123$ is already covered above, hence it only remains to look at the case $m \mid 125$, which forces $m = 5$.

In that case, we have $5 \mid 1 + k \cdot 124^c$ for any odd integer $c$, which implies that $5$ does not divide $1 + k \cdot 124^c$ for any even integer $c$.

Thus we must have $n \mid f(2)$ and $n \mid f(4)$. However, this leads to the same situation as above, now with $a, b = 2, 4$. The same argument then tells us that either $n \mid 123$ (which leads to $n \mid f(c)$ for all $c$) or $n \mid 125$ (which leads to $n = 5$, a contradiction with the assumption $m \neq n$).

---

As can be seen from the proof, one may replace the number $124$ with any number of the form $p^e - 1$ with $p$ prime.